# Overrite template "sales/order/invoice/create/items.phtml"

Tags: magento-1, template, overrides, create-invoice

I want to *overwrite template* file `sales/order/invoice/create/items.phtml` which is define in `sales.xml` like below :

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_invoice_create" name="sales_invoice_create">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_invoice_create_form" name="form" template="sales/order/invoice/create/form.phtml">
                <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_view_info" name="order_info" template="sales/order/view/info.phtml"></block>
                <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_payment" name="order_payment"></block>
                <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_invoice_create_items" name="order_items" template="sales/order/invoice/create/items.phtml">
                 ---- Other Code ---------
</adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
```

I do below code for that

**mymodule.xml**

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
    <reference name="order_items">
           <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_invoice_create_items" name="mymodule" template="mymodule/order/invoice/create/items.phtml">
           </block>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
```

But still,Magento is using default **items.phtml**

**Where I am wrong ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `setTemplate` action:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
    <reference name="order_items">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>mymodule/order/invoice/create/items.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh yes.. :D I forgot this ..